# Wait for function to execute before unloading javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code which i wish to run before the browser refreshes or redirects

```
        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", async (event) => {
        await this.save()
    });
```

the method i'm running involves parsing JSON , updating it , and saving it back to the sessionStorage.Is there a way to make sure this.save() completes before unloading? or at least have it run in the background while the page redirects.

I have tried removing the `async` and `await` code, but does not work.

EDIT here is the save method:

```
 saveCanvas = async (call_back_) => {
    const FlowState = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('FLOWSTATE'))
    ...
    ...
    await html2canvas(div).then((screenshot) => {
           ...
           ...
           sessionStorage.setItem('FLOWSTATE', JSON.stringify(FlowState))
        })
    } 
}
```

Comment: per chance, could you show what the `save` function is? because i have something similar like that but it works.. so changing the `save` function might be the solution or even as terrible as it sounds making it not `async`

Comment: Its all about when you are calling redirect in the code, if it comes before json parsing it will be exequted before too

Comment: @StefanAvramovic is there a way to programatically call the redirect ?

Comment: You can use window.location.href = "http://www.your url here.com";  how is the page beeng redirected currently?

Answer (score 0):

beforeload is the final event before leaving the page(reload leave and reenter for javascript runtime). if you use async functions(include async-await, promise, settimeout) in the event listening functions, it can't be executed anymore.

I think there may be async executions in save function, so it won't work even if you remove async-await keyword.

Comment: yes there is a async function html2canvas , is there a work around to at least make sure the task is carried out in the background

Comment: As far as I know, no  way to do this. you have to remove Promise.then format, try to change logic into sync executions to get it work. If you can't, change your way to set Flowstate.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

Now, I actually suggest you change the layout.. the logic is to have a while loop `await`ing `saveCanvas`(because while behaves well with `await`). So when the page is unloading, the last `html2canvas(div)` would be saved

```
saveCanvas = async(call_back_) => {
  const FlowState = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('FLOWSTATE'))
  await html2canvas(div)
  sessionStorage.setItem('FLOWSTATE', JSON.stringify(FlowState))
}
let toRun=1
while(i){await saveCanvas()}
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (event) => { toRun=0 });
```

Comment: Hmm. this doesnt work, think Eason has mentioned the problem above

Comment: does it work now? i changed the logic to how I'm doing it

Comment: Hmm could you explain the snippet find it difficult to implement without understanding...

Comment: ok, so open ur inspect element and execute this: `let x=;let ioi=1;while(ioi){x=await fetch("https://ipinfo.io/json")}` you would realise that the fetches run smoothly one after the next.. now if you later execute `ioi=0`, `x` would be the last fetch.. in the same manner, when you end the while loop, `sessionStorage` would have the most recent thing set